# Where should the database and mail parameters be stored in a Symfony2 app?

Tags: design, php, database, version-control, symfony

In the default folder structure for a Symfony2 project the database and mail server credentials are stored in `parameters.yml` file inside `ProjectRoot/app/config/parameters.yml` with these default values:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

During development we change these parameters to the development database and mail servers. This file is checked into the source code repository.

The problem is when we want to deploy to the production server. We are thinking about automating the deployment process by checking out the project from git and deploy it to the production server.

The thing is that our project manager has to manually update these parameters after each update. The production database and mail servers parameters are confidential and only our project manager knows them.

I need a way to automate this step and suggestion on where to store the production parameters until they are applied?

Comment: "I need a way to automate this step." http://www.phing.info/

Comment: @YannisRizos yup, but what should I do exactly with Phing? Do we store the database credentials in a file then copy them? where should that file be? better idea than a file?

Comment: Most frameworks have the idea of [environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html). You can load a [different config](https://gist.github.com/lavoiesl/5769521) for test, production, development, etc...

Comment: The simplest (and crudest) solution would be to tell phing to replace your local credentials with the production ones, when you're building for production. That said, as @Mike already mentioned, setting up different configurations per environment is also a good idea (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html). Mike, you should probably expand that comment to an answer.

Comment: Related (not a dupe): [Strategy for keeping secret info such as API keys out of source control?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/205606/25936)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `parameters.yml` to `parameters.yml.sample`, and ignore `parameters.yml` in your version control.

For each installation of the app, copy `.sample` back to the proper location and edit the details as needed.

That way you have a sample file that says what kind of details (mailer, DB, API keys, etc.) each installation needs, and the secrets are never in version control.

Comment: so basically I upload a file with the production parameters to the production server and after each check out I copy it into the project?

Comment: Yep. Or automate it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the last part of the question:  I need a way to automate this step and suggestion on where to store the production parameters until they are applied?  I only point it out because I'm curious since I'll be dealing with this soon myself.

Comment: You can automate your deployment process in a thousand ways -- bash scripts, Ruby scripts, Chef... Where to store the params until they are applied? A secure file on a server that all your production servers can read from? On paper?

Answer (score 0):

For production files you should not be using a file. A much better way that does not interfere with development practices (using the files) is to use ENV variables for your production environment.

Look at the cookbook for reference on this practice:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: What makes you think environment variables are more secure than files with proper permissions?

Comment: 1. The OP asked how to do it programmatically. I don't know about you, but setting an environment variable programmatically seems a bit more practical than creating a file, and populating it.

2. I'm assuming that by "file with proper permissions" you mean the parameters.yaml file which leads to 3.

3. http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-interactive-management-of-the-parameters-yml-file 

4. Read the docs. Don't be lazy. That's what "Makes me think that"

May I suggest that when talking to another person on stack exchange you use a more respectful tone than the one used in your comment?

Comment: Relevance of link #3, in case you're too lazy to read it:
"Please remember that storing password or any other sensitive information in the parameters.yml file is not a good idea, and Symfony provides other ways to do the same in a more secure way."

Comment: Also this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#moving-sensitive-options-outside-of-symfony-entirely

Comment: I totally agree with the env vars and thats what we do. the test servers use the parameters.yml file with totally different credentials, then when deployed to the production cluster those servers have env vars set in the apache vhost configs and symfony uses those without any user intervention. simply deploy and run. it works great